# avoiding iteration using smart dot/matmul on large dataset

Tags: python, numpy

Im trying to write a multi-class perceptron algorithm for the MNIST dataset.

now I have the following code which works, but due to the fact its iterating 60k times it works slowly.

**weights is the size - (785,10)**

```
def multiClassPLA(train_data, train_labels, weights):
    epoch_err = []  # will hold the misclassified ratio for each epoch
    best_weights = weights
    best_error = 1

    for epoch in range(EPOCH):
        err = 0
        # randomize the data before each epoch
        train_data, train_labels = randomizeData(train_data, train_labels)
        for x, y in zip(train_data, train_labels):
            h = oneVsAllLabeling_(np.dot(weights, x))
            diff = (y - h) / 2
            x = x.reshape(1, x.shape[0])
            diff = diff.reshape(CLASSES, 1)

            update_step = ETA * np.dot(diff, x)
            weights += update_step

    return weights
```

**oneVsAllLabeling_(X)** function returns a vector which contain 1 at the argmax and -1 elsewhere. the truth labels has the same form of course.

with this algorithm I'm getting ~90% accuracy, safe but slowly.
after further exploration of the problem I found that I can improve the code using array/matrix multiplication.

so I've started to do the following:

```
def oneVsAllLabeling(X):
    idx = np.argmax(X, axis=1)
    mask = np.zeros(X.shape, dtype=bool)
    mask[np.arange(len(idx)),idx] = 1
    out = 2 * mask - 1
    return out.astype(int)

def zeroOneError(prediction):
    tester = np.zeros((1, CLASSES))
    good_prediction = len(np.where(prediction == tester))
    return len(prediction) - good_prediction

def preceptronModelFitting(data, weights, labels, to_print, epoch=None):
    prediction = np.matmul(data, weights)
    prediction = oneVsAllLabeling(prediction)
    diff = (prediction - labels) / 2
    error = zeroOneError(diff)
    accuracy = error / len(data)
    if to_print:
        print("Epoch: {}. Loss: {}. Accuracy: {}".format(epoch, error, accuracy))
    return prediction, error, accuracy

def multiClassPLA2(train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels, weights):
    predicted_output = np.zeros((1, CLASSES))

    train_loss_vec = np.array([])
    train_accuracy_vec = np.array([])
    test_loss_vec = np.array([])
    test_accuracy_vec = np.array([])

    for epoch in range(EPOCH):
        # randomize the data before each epoch
        train_data, train_labels = randomizeData(train_data, train_labels)
        train_prediction, train_error, train_accuracy = preceptronModelFitting(train_data, weights, train_labels, to_print=False)
    return weights
```

after calling **preceptronModelFitting()** I get a matrix the in the size (60k,10) which every entry has the following shape:

```
train_prediction[0]=[0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0]
```

and the data has the shape (60k, 785)

now what I need to do is, if possible, to multiply each row with each of the data entries and sum so that in total what ill get is a matrix the size (785,10) which I can update with it the old set of weights.

which its almost equivalent to what I do in the not efficient algorithm, the only differance is that I update the weights every new data entry instead of after seeing all the data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK you did most of the job done, and even you had part of the answer in your title.

```
np.matmul(X.T, truth - prediction)
```

Using this, it will get you what you want in a one line.
notice that this based on the fact that indeed truth, prediction, X are as you mentioned.